# VBA code to create formula depending on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, cell

I have a spreadsheet with values in cells A to G.

I need to read the data in Cell F, and depending on the data, formulate a hyperlink into the corresponding cell in column H, with the data from cell G (next to F) inserted within the hyperlink.

EG 1

Cell F contains : DPD

Cell g contains : 123456

Desire cell H to create hyperlink :

=HYPERLINK("http://www.dpd.co.uk/tracking/quicktrack.do?search.consignmentNumber="&CELLG*&"&search.searchType=16&search.javascriptValidated=0&appmode=guest")

EG 2

Cell F contains : TNT

Cell g contains : abcde

Desire cell H to create hyperlink :

=HYPERLINK("http://www.tnt.com/express/en_gb/site/searchresults.html?q=**CELLG**")

I have many more other values in cell F which rely on a different hyperlink formula, but I should be able to repeat and alter the code to cater for those values.

UPDATED:

This is my current attempt at applying the formula.

```
  Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-2]=""dpd"",HYPERLINK(""http://www.dpd.co.uk/tracking/quicktrack.do?search.consignmentNumber=""&RC[-1]&""&search.searchType=16&search.javascriptValidated=0&appmode=guest""))"
Range("I1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("i1:i" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillCopy
 Range("I2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("A1:I1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:i1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="FALSE"
   Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(R[-1]C[-2]=""City Link"",HYPERLINK(""http://www.packagetrackr.com/track/citylink/""&R[-1]C[-1]&""""))"
  Range("I2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("i2:i" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillCopy

Range("A1:I1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:i1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="FALSE"
Range("i2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(R[-1]C[-2]=""hermes"",HYPERLINK(""http://www.hermes-europe.co.uk/tracker.html?trackingNumber=""&R[-1]C[-1]&""&Postcode=""&R[-1]C[-4]&R[-1]C[-3]&""""))"
  Range("I2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("i2:i" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillCopy

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Range("I2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("I1").Select
```

I cannot figure out how to autofill on a filtered list.

Maybe I need to try the loop through method?

FAILED FORMULA:

=IF(G2="hermes",HYPERLINK("www.hermes-europe.co.uk/tracker.html?trackingNumber="&H2&"&Postcode="&e2&f2&"),IF(G2="Parcelforce",HYPERLINK("www.parcelforce.com/track-trace?trackNumber="&h2&"),IF(G2="Royal Mail",HYPERLINK("www.royalmail.com/track-trace?track=track&trackNumber="&h2&"&gear=track&imageRootPath=&loc=en_GB&default=default&emt=emt"),IF(G2="Yodel",HYPERLINK("www.myyodel.co.uk/tracking?parcel_id="&h2&"&postcode="&e2&"%23"&f2&"),IF(G2="4 Square",HYPERLINK("login.smartconsign.co.uk/trackingcust.aspx?partnerid=EAFSQ001&jobno="&h2&"),IF(G2="Deutsche Post",HYPERLINK("nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=en&idc="&h2&"&rfn=&extendedSearch=true"),IF(g2="No Tracking","&h2&")"""))))

Comment: What role does Col F play in creating those hyperlinks? I can see Col G being used in the formula...

Comment: Well col F will dictate which formula will be entered into Col H.. eg if cell f were to contain "TNT" then the desired formula to be entered into cell h would be =HYPERLINK("http://www.tnt.com/express/en_gb/site/searchresults.html?q=CELL G)

Comment: And how would it dictate that? Where have you mentioned that above?

Comment: I mean what should happen in cell F has `DPD` or `TNT` or `Something` else?

Comment: Sorry  my post wasn't clear

Comment: Oh you mean in the URL after "www"?

Comment: ok so for example, if cell F has DPD then cell H would contain =HYPERLINK("http://www.dpd.co.uk/tracking/quicktrack.do?search.consignmentNumber="&CELLG*&"&search.searchType=16&search.javascriptValidated=0&appmode=guest").. and if cell f has TNT, then cell H would contain =HYPERLINK("tnt.com/express/en_gb/site/searchresults.html?q=CELL G).. hopefully if i can get the code regarding dpd then i can repeat it and alter it if it finds TNT, i can put in the hyperlinks manually

Comment: Updated my post: Check it now. You will have to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the relevant cell's address rather than `CELLG`. See this example.

This goes in cell `H1`

To do a comparision in an Excel formula you can use the `IF` formula

Example

`=If(Condition,Do if Cond is true, Do if Cond is False)`

so

`=IF(F2="TNT",Do Something if equal to TNT,Do Something if not equal to TNT))`

or

`=IF(F2="DPD",Do Something if equal to DPD,Do Something if not equal to DPD))`

Combining the above two will give

`=IF(F2="TNT",Do Something if equal to TNT,IF(F2="DPD",Do Something if equal to DPD,Do Something if not equal to DPD)))`

If TNT then use this website

`http://www.tnt.com/express/en_gb/site/searchresults.html?q=`

If DPD then use this website

`http://www.dpd.co.uk/tracking/quicktrack.do?search.consignmentNumber=`

All we have to do now is append it to the above formula

`=IF(F1="TNT",HYPERLINK("http://www."&F1&".com/express/en_gb/site/searchresults.html?q="&
G1&
"&search.searchType=16&search.javascriptValidated=0&appmode=guest"),IF(F1="DPD",HYPERLINK("http://www."&F1&".co.uk/tracking/quicktrack.do?search.consignmentNumber="&
G1&
"&search.searchType=16&search.javascriptValidated=0&appmode=guest"),""))`

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but for each value in cell f, will have a different hyperlink address. eg dpd website and tnt website will have different addresses?

Comment: Can you update your question with examples for TNT and DPD and also mention what those websites are

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way you could give me the VBA code for this function?

Comment: I can but I want you to try it first :) Two ways I can think of `1` Copy the formula from above and then record a macro and then put the formula in cell H1. Stop the macro and see how the code writes the formula `2` Write a code to loop through col F and check what the values are and then construct your If statement. :) Give it a try and if you are stuck then simply post the code that you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The formula works perfectly. Will try what you suggested, and get back to you if i get stuck.. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Siddharth, can i ask you another question?

Comment: if it is related to this question then you may ask here. If it is a different question then ideally it should go as a new question :)

Comment: Any ideas? I cant seem to figure out how to do it

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that. BTW why are you filtering the list? If you check my formula, you don't need to filter anything to apply it. Depending on what is in Col F, it is automatically create the hyperlink.

Comment: Your formula was very useful, but i couldnt use more than 7 IF functions. It wouldnt allow it. I think there may be a limit to how many can be done?

Comment: Which excel version are you using? Excel 2003?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx you can have 64 levels unlike xl2003 where you can have only 7 ;)

Comment: Maybe i was making a mistake with the brackets? my failed formula is above..ive removed the "http" as it wouldnt allow me to post more than 2 links (reputation).

Comment: The first thing that you need to do is write individual formulas and then embed them inside one another like I did in my post above. If there are 10 conditions then write 10 different formulas and then embed them together...

Comment: Yes, after you did that, i did the very same thing. I compiled each individual formula, but when i put it into excel, it wouldn't accept it  :(

Comment: can you post individual formulas in a text file one below the other and then upload it to www.wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Comment: heres the link:  http://wikisend.com/download/536478/Hyperlink formulas.txt]Hyperlink formulas.txt....bear in mind im not that good with brackets and speech marks..thank you for your help

Comment: No worries Siddharth, its all sorted :).. thank you again for all your help!

Comment: OK im back...i seem to be getting an error message when i try to combine more than 8 functions.. "You've entered too many arguments for this function".   Heres the URL to what ive done so far.  http://wikisend.com/download/315342/Hyperlink%20formulas.txt   if you could have a look i would be very grateful. Thank you so much