# VLOOKUP & Inserting Text That Corresponds To The Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm having difficulty getting my vlookup formula to pull url data from another sheet (Sheet 2) and insert added information to the url based on what is in its A cell on Sheet 1.

For example,

The vlookup formula `=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)` will check to see if B2 (Sheet 1) matches with Data on Sheet 2. It will then return the data it has matched:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.dpd.co.uk/tracking/quicktrack.do?search.consignmentNumber="&Sheet1!A2&"&search.searchType=16&search.javascriptValidated=0&appmode=guest")
```

I then want the url link to insert whatever text is in the **Sheet 1 A cell**.

The formula I have used does this nicely, but I want the formula to correspond down the workbook for whatever is in cell A, not just A1 i.e. Sheet 1 A3,Sheet 1 A4....

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you just want this formula copied down and for it to keep the relative reference i.e. the current row? Are you entering this in a1 of sheet 1? And does the hyperlink function work you've entered?

Comment: I **think** what you are looking for is a list of all values in `Sheet2`, `Column B` that match `Sheet1`, Cell `B2` to be returned in a list filling down `Sheet1` column `A`?

Comment: GLH, I would like it copied down and have it insert the relative reference/current row. The hyperlink works

Comment: `relative reference` And `current row` would be 2 different beasts. relative reference's i would ***Assume*** you would want ONLY matches. With current row it would have a result for **EVERYTHING** in `Sheet2!B` and an indicator of if it was a Match or not.

Comment: Aha.. Whats up with [DPD sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101581/macro-to-create-formula-depending-on-cell-value) ;)

Comment: If you copy and paste this cell down it will keep the relative reference to the column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you are asking but allow me to share my experience with what I believe was a similar problem.
My solution was an offset/match formula. I used a formula similar to:
=OFFSET($A$1,(MATCH(B$2,'Sheet2'!$A:$B,0)+$A1),0)
And had a list of values in column A that corresponded to the distance that row was to the object cell I wanted to keep constant. Then I used autofill to fill column a down the sheet as far as I filled the formula. This way offset refrence changed on each row and I was still able to auto fill.
I hope that helps